# Couldn't convert HTML to PDF using iText lib

Tags: android, html, pdf, itext, htmltidy

I am pre-parsing HTML with *HTML Tidy*.

Then I use the resulting cleaned HTML to create a PDF, using *iText*.

It works great but some htmls couldn't be converted. Here is an example:

**HTML** (not parsed by HTML Tidy)

```html
<html><head></head><body style="background: white; font-size: 15px;">





<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:RelyOnVML/>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->


<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Normal</w:View>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:TrackMoves>false</w:TrackMoves>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>RU</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
   <w:SnapToGridInCell/>
   <w:WrapTextWithPunct/>
   <w:UseAsianBreakRules/>
   <w:DontGrowAutofit/>
   <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>
   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
   <w:DontFlipMirrorIndents/>
   <w:OverrideTableStyleHps/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   <m:brkBinSub m:val="&#45;-"/>
   <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
   <m:dispDef/>
   <m:lMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:rMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"/>
   <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"/>
   <m:intLim m:val="subSup"/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="true"
  DefSemiHidden="true" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="267">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="toc 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="35" QFormat="true" Name="caption"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="10" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" Name="Default Paragraph Font"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="11" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtitle"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="22" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Strong"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="20" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="59" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Table Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Placeholder Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="No Spacing"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Revision"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="34" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="List Paragraph"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="29" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="30" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Shading Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Light Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Dark List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful List Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="19" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtle Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="21" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="31" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtle Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="32" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Intense Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="33" SemiHidden="false"
   UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Book Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="37" Name="Bibliography"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" QFormat="true" Name="TOC Heading"/>
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]-->

<!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
 {mso-style-name:"Обычная таблица";
 mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
 mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
 mso-style-noshow:yes;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-style-parent:"";
 mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
 mso-para-margin:0cm;
 mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 mso-pagination:none;
 text-autospace:ideograph-other;
 font-size:12.0pt;
 font-family:"Times New Roman","serif";
 mso-bidi-font-family:Tahoma;
 mso-font-kerning:1.5pt;
 mso-ansi-language:DE;
 mso-fareast-language:JA;
 mso-bidi-language:FA;}
</style>
<![endif]-->



<!--StartFragment-->

<p class="Standard"><span lang="RU" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Open Sans';">С&nbsp;момента появления на&nbsp;модном
пространстве Узбекистана бренд About неоднократно «волновал» публику. Дело
не&nbsp;только в&nbsp;новом подходе к&nbsp;пошиву одежды,
но&nbsp;и&nbsp;в&nbsp;кардинально новом взгляде на&nbsp;понятие стиля
и&nbsp;внешнего облика. На&nbsp;упреки в&nbsp;«неформальности» бренд отвечал
ясно и&nbsp;понятно&nbsp;— они создают одежду для тех, кто любит перемены
и&nbsp;открыт новому.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class="Standard"><span lang="RU" style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: 'Open Sans';"><img src="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/attachments/347b9594-4a68-45d5-9bbf-6a7bf7b6434b/Inline image.jpg"></span></p>

<p class="Textbody" style="margin-top:10.5pt;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:10.5pt;
margin-left:0cm"><span style="font-size: 10pt;"><v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
 <v:stroke joinstyle="miter">
 <v:formulas>
  <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0">
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0">
  <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1">
  <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2">
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth">
  <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight">
  <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1">
  <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2">
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth">
  <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0">
  <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight">
  <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0">
 </v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:f></v:formulas>
 <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect">
 <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t">
</o:lock></v:path></v:stroke></v:shapetype><v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:510pt;
 height:339pt;visibility:visible" o:bordertopcolor="#eee" o:borderleftcolor="#eee" o:borderbottomcolor="#eee" o:borderrightcolor="#eee">
 <v:imagedata src="file:///C:\Users\Eugenia\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_image001.jpg" o:href="http://www.afisha.uz/ui/materials/2015/08/1007017_b.jpg">
 <w:bordertop type="single" width="2">
 <w:borderleft type="single" width="2">
 <w:borderbottom type="single" width="2">
 <w:borderright type="single" width="2">
</w:borderright></w:borderbottom></w:borderleft></w:bordertop></v:imagedata></v:shape></span><span lang="DE"><a name="wysiwyg_img_83981"></a><o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class="Standard"><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Droid Sans&quot;;
color:#222222;mso-ansi-language:EN-US">ANALYST VIEW: "The Fed appears to
be heading toward a rate hike and this against the backdrop of deflationary
forces globally is creating intense uncertainty," Shane Oliver, head of
investment and chief economist at AMP Capital, said in a commentary.
"Investors have now grown used to near zero interest rates for more than 6
years in the U.S. and there is naturally fear that raising them will threaten
the still fragile U.S. and global economies."<o:p></o:p></span></p>

<!--EndFragment--><div class="sig">--<br>Sent by MyMail. Privacy is an essential element of human liberty. Remind someone.</div></body></html>
```

**CODE**

```
try {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance
                (document, new FileOutputStream(absoluteFilePath));
        document.open();
        if (htmlText == null || htmlText.trim().isEmpty()) {
            htmlText = "";
            document.add(new Chunk(""));
        }

        // Fixing xhtml tag
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); // obtain a new Tidy instance
        tidy.setXHTML(true); // set desired config options using tidy setters
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tidy.setCharEncoding(Configuration.UTF8);
        tidy.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlText.getBytes()), output); // run tidy, providing an input and output stream
        String preparedText = output.toString("UTF-8");

   //            Log.i("CHECKING", "JTidy Out: " + preparedText);

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(preparedText.getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document,
                inputStream, null, Charset.defaultCharset(), new MyFont());
        document.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        File file = new File(absoluteFilePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
            LOGGER.info("PDF isDeleted: " + isDeleted);
        }
        LOGGER.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

As a result `preparedText` *(the text that comes out of HTML Tidy)* will be empty. iText then throws a *No pages exception* when it gets empty input from HTML Tidy. Why tidy returns empty text? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your post: remove the original HTML and replace it with the cleaned up HTML you got from Tidy. Because it is unclear now what iText gets as input.

Comment: The HTML got from Tidy is empty. Maybe error occurs when Tidy parsing proccess.

Comment: With the W3C Validator you can also tidy your HTML. Copy and paste that as input HTML for iText.

Comment: Can you give me example how can i check validation with W3C Validator?

Comment: No I can not. It's just a website where you can copy and paste your HTML, click some checkboxes, and get a report on your HTML. It's only supposed to be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: I also suggest that you refactor your code: extract the 6 lines about Tidy to a separate method, and make sure that you check only that method first. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I have checked my html via https://validator.w3.org/check it gives to me 60 errors :(((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105093/discussion-between-nakhmedov-and-amedee-van-gasse).

Comment: *The HTML got from Tidy is empty.* - so this is no iText issue but an issue of your html in combination with tidy. You should re-tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, the url was wrong. You need https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Anyway 4 exception,  i need to do Tidy ignore if something fails

Comment: @mkl I ninja'd your edit...

Comment: @nAkhmedov reduce your question to the simplest possible problem. Remove all code that is related to iText, and only keep the code that is needed for HTML Tidy. As I have written above, refactor your code: extract the HTML Tidy functionality to a separate method, and test only that method. If you use Eclipse, this is how you do it: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-ExtractMethod.htm

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse ROTFL!